# Why is Java JPackage installing Windows dll files in two places?

Tags: java, java-14, jpackage

Why is Java JPackage installing Windows dll files in two places ?

My **Jlink** cmd is:

*"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-14.0.0.36-hotspot\bin\jlink" --module-path="C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-14.0.0.36-hotspot\jmods"  --add-modules java.desktop,java.datatransfer,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.net.http,java.prefs,java.scripting,java.sql,jdk.management,jdk.unsupported,jdk.scripting.nashorn,jdk.jcmd --output C:\code\jthink\jaikoz\windowsjre\JVM64*

and my build command is

*"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-14.0.0.36-hotspot\bin\jpackage" -i C:\Code\jthink\jaikoz\target\Jaikoz\activebuild\buildWindows\lib --runtime-image C:\code\jthink\jaikoz\windowsjre\JVM64 --main-class com.jthink.Jaikoz --name Jaikoz --win-dir-chooser --main-jar jaikoz.jar --app-version 10.2.0 --install-dir Jthink2\Jaikoz --copyright "Copyright Info" --arguments "-l2 -m2 -f" --vendor JThink*

They are installed directly in the installation folder, and in the **runtime/bin** folder, is it meant to do this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Interesting. You may want to ask on the mailing list or submit a bug report to see if this is intended behavior. I don't see why it would be though.

Comment: It looks like applauncher.dll is the only one that is used in the top level directory

Comment: @DuncG do yo have a WIndows installer, and if so do yo seem the same behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in jpackage which is reported here but not marked with a fix version [JDK-8236744](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236744), and several duplicates one of which says fix version 15: [JDK-8230863](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8230863)

All DLLs except applauncher.dll could be deleted from the root of install directory, but they will keep returning for time being...

Comment: I did search this, but searching for jpackage does not appear to bring back any of the bugs you found !

Comment: Just tried Java 15EA - https://jdk.java.net/15/ and this doesn't install any DLLS in the root dir.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I can recommend using the advanced search option. Looks like they use component = tools and subcomponent = jpackage for the issues: [Link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8248864?jql=component%20%3D%20tools%20AND%20Subcomponent%20%3D%20jpackage%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC)