# Can you use Java JPackage to create own Windows installer without using its way of running application

Tags: java-14, jpackage

Background, I currently use **Izpack** for my Windows installer, I bundle a java runtime and use **winrun4j** as a wrapper both for the installation and the actual program once installed. It worked for a long time but there are a number of problems with the installer that I have not been able to solve and have been looking to replace it.

Oracle now provide the JPackage installer so it seems like a sensible choice. But the folder structure created by the installer is different to what I currently have, I have a number of config and non java files and I have not been able to get the .exe that JPackage creates to do anything.

So is it possible to use JPackage to create the installer but in a strcuture better matching my existing structure, and use continue to use WInRun4j to actyally run my application

Existing Folder Structure

```
ROOT
---App.exe
---Config Files
---lib
-------jar files
---JVM64
------- Java runtime
---help
```

JPackage structure

```
ROOT
---App.exe
---Runtime Dlls
---app
----- jar files
      Config files
--runtime
------Java runtime
------Runtime Dlls (again)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of directories generated by jpackage is mainly set up for you and does not seem possible to change, and makes installation of Java app dependencies very easy with self contained JRE. The basic structure for Windows is as you say:

```
ROOT
---App.exe (for --main-class parameter) 
---xyz.exe (for each --add-launcher parameter)
---Runtime Dlls (these appear to be unused except for applauncher.dll, see SO 62607300)
---app/
------App.cfg (for --main-class)
------xyz.cfg (for per --add-launcher)
---runtime/
------Java runtime
------Runtime Dlls
```

With `--input` and `--main-jar` params you are free to setup additional directory structure under app/ folder for anything else you want for your application. So if you used `lib/myappjar.jar` it would add:

```
---app/
-------lib/
----------myappjar.jar
```

If you used `--input build\mypath` it would copy the entire tree of files under that folder, so if `build\mypath` dir contained

```
bin/
---Scripts
---xyz.properties
README.txt
```

Then app would also contain:

```
---app/
------bin/
---------Scripts
---------xyz.properties
------README.txt
```

By the way the Runtime DLLs placed at top level appear to be copies of some of the DLLs under runtime/bin
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607300/why-is-java-jpackage-installing-windows-dll-files-in-two-places]

Comment: So in summary I can define the structure underneath app as I wish, but I cannot put anything directly into Root folder, and provide an alternative .exe file at that level ? I know the DLLs are copies, but dont understand why, do yo think that is how it is meant wo work or a bug.

Comment: Yes the structure under app can be as you wish for storing any related files, plus remember of course mixed with a generated app/x.cfg per x.exe in the root. System prop `java.library.path` is set for the root dir + app dir so you have native code it should be in app dir or add more --java-options. `java.launcher.path` is set when running .exe, which appears to be the install directory. I think the duplicate DLL copies is bug in current release.

Comment: OK getting somewhere but I have code like ' origLayout = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), filename);' so assume config files are in same folder as where run exe, but now one folder below (app), I can change my code or id there a way to chnage the installer config to make user.dir be the app folder ?

Comment: You could launch from a script or shortcut I suppose but thats no good for dbl-click. I had same issue as you, and ended up adding a small extra code to read System property `java.launcher.path` first and add "app", before fall back the original code path location. I'm not sure this works on Linux as the dir structure is slightly different (why!?). Let me know any other ideas you find.

Comment: okay, is there any reason why java.launcher.path would ever be any different to user.dir (on windows)

Comment: Yes. Although they would match when double click EXE in Windows Explorer as java.launcher.path would always be the path to the top of installation directory (if EXE used), but note user.dir is set to a directory by the context of what was doing the launch. Example it would use the current working dir of a interactive cmd.exe / .cmd / .bat file, or the "Start in:" value of a shortcut link which could be wholly different place.

Comment: @DuncG, is there any way that I could input a file into the runtime folder ?  how and where to write  the input ?

Comment: @Noor Hossain Add a question if stuck, try something like `jpackage --type app-image --dest {somedir} ...` to generate, then edit the release image under {somedir}, then `jpackage --dest {somedir} --type exe --app-image {somedir}/{imagename}` should pack up the modifications.